# Interpolation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, interpolation

I have this [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) code

```
$("#selector").html('<a href=url>text</a>');
```

where `url` and `text` are JavaScript variables. How would I evaluate them inside quotes?

Comment: I created an open source project for interpolation you can try. https://github.com/zsong/Kiwi Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just concatenate the strings together with `+`:

```
$('#selector').html('<a href='+url+'>'+text+'</a>');
```

Answer (score 2):

While @kingjiv's answer is absolutely right, if you'll be doing a lot of templating with jQuery it might be worth checking out the [tmpl](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl)* plugin to help keep things organized.

***note:** This plugin never made it past beta, and is no longer being maintained, the link above is for archival purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing here post 2015: use [ES6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). These are string literals, enclosed in backticks, which allow embedded expressions.

```
$('#selector').html(`<a href='${url}'>${text}</a>`);
```