# How do I integrate variable in strings (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

I am trying to do something like this:

```
var newPositionOnX = 400px;

$(".element").css("transform", "translate(0,newPositionOnX)");
```

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interpolation in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644618/interpolation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var newPositionOnX = 400;
$(".element").css("transform", "translate(0, " + newPositionOnX + "px)");
```